# Supplying an object where a Action is expected as callback

Tags: c#, callback, action

I have a method that expects a callback that is defined as Action callback.
I am wondering whether I can supply an object that implements a function with that signature instead, I need to bundle some additional information, and it would be convenient to do it in the constructor of said object. Java would allow you to typically do this, wondering if such support lives in C# or whether there are any alternatives.

thanks

Comment: As far as I know, C# does not have language constructs for making a _callable object_. You can, however, have a member method of an object casted to an `Action` and remain bound to its instance quite easily as long as its return value is `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates of instance methods are bound to the instance of the object, so you can do this:

```
public class MyObject
{
   private string _value;
   public MyObject(string v) { _value = v; }
   public void TheCallBack() {
      Console.WriteLine(_value);
   }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var obj = new MyObject("Test value");
Action a = obj.TheCallback;
a();  // This will output "Test value"
```

So there really isn't a need for any sort of special object